# Regular expression for picking double cruelly braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as shown below.Can you tell me how to pick the numeric part of it?
i.e. `28903220`

**Note:** This `{{` and `answer_` and closing this `}}` are common for all the strings.

`var test = "Is {{answer_28903220}} physically ready to night wean?"`

Comment: `/{{answer_(\d+)}}/`? You are a "Senior ASP.net MVC (C#) / Angular / Ionic Full-stack Freelance developer at Upwork". Is this a prank?

Comment: I don't like regex. I always ask here when I have a requirement :)  @d4nyll

Comment: Haha. Got it (:

Comment: use this /{{.*}}/  to get whole part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`/{{answer_(\d+)}}/`

```
const test = "Is {{answer_28903220}} physically ready to night wean?"
const matches = test.match(/{{answer_(\d+)}}/);
matches[1]; // "28903220"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the whole this part too `{{answer_28903220}}`?

Comment: use this /{{.*}}/ for whole part

Comment: The numeric part, as stated, is in index 1 of resulting `matches` - `matches[1]`. The whole match is in index 0 of the result - `matches[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment *whole this part too {{answer_28903220}}*

use this`/{{.*}}/`

Answer (score 0):

`match(/\d+/g])` should return the numbers as long there are no other numbers in your string.